# Qt how do you add to the Windows Title bar?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the follow example (from GlassWire) and I know it was built using Qt but I can't seem to figure out how to put stuff in the "Windows Title Bar" the semi translucent part of the Window Frame. Like in this example, we have a QPushButton GlassWire button and then we have 4 tabs, all in the normal Windows frame.

I can't seem to figure out how to do something like that. Any ideas on how I could, for example, add a QPushButton in the bar?

I would do something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx if I was doing this outside of Qt.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it done by doing something like this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWin>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    QtWin::enableBlurBehindWindow(this);
    QtWin::extendFrameIntoClientArea(this, -1, -1, -1, -1);
#endif
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```